# Python: Регуляка для Хидера

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, header

Суть такова что ищу одну строчку и если она есть то тру, если нет то false.
Что можно подобрать оптимального для этого по скорости?

**UPD:**
Вот решение

```
urllib2.urlopen(request).info().get('X-Pingback', '')
```

Comment: сравнение строк не пробовали?

Comment: Профилировщиком уже выявлено, что это место является узким по производительности?  
Быстрее всего будет текстовый поиск по точному совпадению.  
В случае многократного применения и не точного совпадения быстрее будет регулярное выражение, так как питон скриптовый язык.

Comment:     index в питоне есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[string.find](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html?highlight=substring#string.find)